# How to test file creation with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, file-io, rspec

I have a simple `FileCreator` Ruby class that has 1 method `create` which creates a blank txt file on my desktop. Using RSpec, how would I test this create method to make sure 
that the file was created, without having to create the file? Would I use `RSpec::Mocks`? Can someone please point me in the right directory? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After calling `file_creator.create(100)` you could search the folder for all `File*.txt` files and make sure the count matches. (Make sure to have your spec remove the test files after completion).

```
Dir.glob(File.join(File.expand_path("~/Desktop"), "File*.txt")).length.should == 100
```

Using Mocks: You could do something like this to verify that the `File.open` method is actually being called (to test that the files actually get created, though, you may want to consider actually creating the files like the first half of my answer).

```
File.should_receive(:open).exactly(100).times
```

Comment: That is the way I figured I would have to do it. What I was wondering was if there is a way to use a mock object or something so I wouldn't have to create the files in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using something like [FakeFS](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs) which mocks the actual file system.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is as below:

```
FileCreator.count.should eq 100
```